# Zip Azure Blob Files in C# Getting Damaged

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to zip my blob storage file with ZipArchive and uploading that zip stream back to blob storage.

Below is the code for downloading the file stream into Zip Entry and uploading back to blob storage, But the problem is that when I go back to storage explorer and download my zip file it gives me this error:

**The archive is either unknown format or damaged**

```html
    var account = _cloudStorageAccount;
                var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference("myFiles");
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myFile.pdf");
                MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream();
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create  , true))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry orderEntry = zip.CreateEntry("myFile.pdf");
                    using (Stream entryStream = orderEntry.Open())
                    {
                        var cloudBlockClient = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myFile.pdf");
                        await cloudBlockClient.DownloadToStreamAsync(entryStream);
                    }
                    CloudBlobContainer _blobContainer = _blobClient.GetContainerReference("protocol");
                    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlobZip = _blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("Fifth.zip");
                    cloudBlockBlobZip.Properties.ContentType = "zip";
                    zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    zipStream.Position = 0;
                    await cloudBlockBlobZip.UploadFromStreamAsync(zipStream);
                    var fileUrl = cloudBlockBlobZip.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                    return zipStream;
                }
```

Comment: Hmm, you could try instead of DownloadToStreamAsync to start download (returns a Stream), and then use CopyAsync on the stream to copy it to the entryStream.

Comment: I've used BeginDownloadToStream but give me output in AsyncCallback, so in callback i can't set stream into zip entry.

Comment: That's not the right one, that's older style async. Are you using the newer _Azure.Storage.Blobs_ library or the older one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code. I use new storage SDK `Azure.Storage.Blobs`.

```
 string[] blobs = { "",... };
            string connectionString = "";
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            var sourceContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("input");
            var desContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("output");
            var desBlob= desContainer.GetBlockBlobClient( "my.zip");
            var options = new BlockBlobOpenWriteOptions {
                HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders {
                    ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("my.zip"),
                },
            };
          using (var outStream = await desBlob.OpenWriteAsync(true, options).ConfigureAwait(false))
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create)) {
                foreach (var blob in blobs)
                {
                    var source = sourceContainer.GetBlobClient(blob);
                    var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(blob, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                    // approach 1
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        await source.DownloadToAsync(entryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        entryStream.Close();
                    }

                }
            }
```